# Asserting string matches regex in pytest

Tags: python, regex, pytest, assert, assertion

I'm writing up a test using pytest to ensure a timestamp string that gets passed in matches the appropriate regex format. I have done this the following way.

```
test_epoch():
    timestamp = "1541811598.802"
    epoch_regex = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+$')
    assert epoch_regex.match(epoch)
```

However, when the test runs, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: assert None
+  where None = <built-in method match of re.Pattern object at 0x11ade6480>('1541840398.802')
+    where <built-in method match of re.Pattern object at 0x11ade6480> = re.compile('^[0-9]+$').match
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong and how to properly assert a string matches regex?

Comment: you're not using timestamp at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `timestamp` really match the regular expression? What happens if you get rid of the `'.'` in `timestamp`? I have a feeling `timestamp = "1541811598802"` would pass.

Also keep in mind that `'.'` is a special character in regular expressions, so when you modify your regex make sure you account for this (hint, escape special chars with `\`)!